# generate normalized discrete values for feature engineering

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

There is a dataframe, with one columns store the discrete values, shown as follows. I would like to create another column storing the normalized values. For instance, for `4050`, the corresponding entry will be `4`. Are there any efficient ways to do that instead of writing my own function? In Sklearn, are there any functions to generating normalized values?

[image]

Comment: Why would the corresponding entry be 4? What kind of normalization are you going for? there are lots of ways to normalize data...

Comment: there are around 20 different values, and the range is from 1000 to 9999, so I would like to use every 1000 as a category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment:

> *there are around 20 different values, and the range is from 1000 to 9999, so I would like to use every 1000 as a category*

This isn't really normalization in the strict sense of the word. However, to do that, you can easily use floor division (`//`):

```
df['new_column'] = df['values']//1000
```

For example:

```
>>> df
   values
0    2021
1    8093
2    9870
3    4508
4    2645
5    1441
6    8888
7    8921
8    7292
9    8571

df['new_column'] = df['values']//1000

>>> df
   values  new_column
0    2021           2
1    8093           8
2    9870           9
3    4508           4
4    2645           2
5    1441           1
6    8888           8
7    8921           8
8    7292           7
9    8571           8
```

Comment: Thanks, do you have any suggestions on how to better normalize them?

Comment: Like I said, this isn't normalization. I'm not sure what you're going for, but if you wanted to normalize them to have a mean of 0 and a standard deviation of 1, I'd suggest using [`StandardScaler`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html), but that's a completely different thing from what you're asking, I think.